# Problems with a second order differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following second order differential equation to solve,

$$y''(t)+7y(t)y'(t)=6y(t)(c_1-(y(t))^2)$$

Where c1 is just a constant and y is of inverse seconds unit. I have tried separation of variables and making a few substitutions, which both turned out to be useless. Additionally, I am not given any initial conditions. If anyone has an idea on even approaching this problem, let alone solving it, it would greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least the eigenvalues around the origin are in resonance...

Comment: @Moo Doesn't the lack of initial conditions not allow me to solve it numerically?